# How do I toggle between even/odd elements for a tic-tac-toe game

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop, if-statement

I have a function that adds a class oPiece while the counter is even and the class xPiece while odd. The current for-loop however only adds the class xPiece every time I click a div (with class=box)

JS

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      $(this).addClass('oPiece');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('xPiece');
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="1"></div>
  <div class="box" id="2"></div>
  <div class="box" id="3"></div>
  <div class="box" id="4"></div>
  <div class="box" id="5"></div>
  <div class="box" id="6"></div>
  <div class="box" id="7"></div>
  <div class="box" id="8"></div>
  <div class="box" id="9"></div>
</div>
<button class="resetBtn">Reset</button>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.oPiece {
  background-color: blue;
}
.xPiece {
  background-color: red;
}
.resetBtn {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Here is the link to my codepen --> https://codepen.io/jdk301/pen/LYbeeOX

Answer (score 1):

when click the div(class=box),will execute once for statement. In the end of for statement the value of i is seven so div addclass always 'xPiece'.

change the js code:

```
    let num = 0;
$('.box').click(function() {
  // for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  //   console.log(i)
  //   if (i % 2 == 0) {
  //     $(this).addClass('oPiece');
  //   } else {
  //     $(this).addClass('xPiece');
  //   }
  // }
  num++;
     if (num % 2 == 0) {
      $(this).addClass('oPiece');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('xPiece');
    }

});
```